# How to display the drawer list without overlapping using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

HI, I'm new to Material-UI, I've created a drawer but the problem is when i click on the Menu then it is going inside the drawer. Even if i do inspect, i minimize the page again the drawer is getting overlapped. My objective is -  if i minimize the page a little bit also the table should get adjust with the page width, it should not go inside the drawer. Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: In the Case you have to move your entire body toward right side or left side which is based the drawer which you are aiming.... when you click on menu button you need to create one class for body tag. Using that class you can do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54112129/11872246

Comment: @keikai - Yes, Thank you so much for helping me :) :). I was trying from 1 week. you've solved my problem

Comment: @keikai - In that link, within `drawer` tag the whole table was given but here i'm using routing method. Can you assist me in this?

Comment: @Sandhya okay, I will try it later if you are not in a hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some changes in your existing code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-lovelace-7efpl

You can check the above link. Basically, you need to give `sidebarWidth = margin-left` in the component beside sidebar.

This is important because sidebar has a fixed positioning. So if something is added beside it it will go behind the sidebar. Material UI grid is not required according to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot :).  You've solved my issue :). Thank you so much